# Proving an identity relating the gamma matrices

Tags: momentum, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

I'm looking to prove the following identity:

$$k_a \gamma^a \gamma^\nu K_b \gamma^b p_c \gamma^c \gamma_\nu P_d \gamma^d = 4(p\cdot K)(P\cdot k)$$
I tried this many times but always seem to be stuck in a loop with two $\gamma$-s multiplying my final expression. 
What I've used during my calculation are the following two things $$\gamma^\nu \gamma_\nu =4$$
as well as the anti-commutation relations the $\gamma$-s satisfy $$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\} = 2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$
The final expression I reach is the following 
$$4(p\cdot K)k_aP_d\gamma^a \gamma^d$$

I'd be happy to get some help with this.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a trace on the left hand side of the identity?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the identity is not always correct. If $p$ and $K$ have only the zero-th components $p_0\neq 0$ and $K_0\neq 0$, we get your "final expression" in the left-hand side. If then $k$ has only the zero-th component $k_0\neq 0$ and $P$ has only the first component $P_1\neq 0$, we obtain an incorrect equality $4p_0 K_0 k_0 P_1 \gamma^0 \gamma^1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your identity appears to equate a 4x4 matrix to a number. If one inserts an identity matrix on the right-hand-side to fix this, the equality does not hold. Therefore I think you have omitted a trace on the left-hand-side. However, then the right-hand-side is off by a factor of 4.

I think that what you are trying to show is actually

$$\text{Tr}(k_a \gamma^a \gamma^\nu K_b \gamma^b p_c \gamma^c \gamma_\nu P_d \gamma^d) = 16(p\cdot K)(P\cdot k).$$

This follows from

$$\gamma^\nu \gamma^b \gamma^c \gamma_\nu = 4 \eta^{bc} I$$

and

$$\text{Tr}(\gamma^a \gamma^d) = 4 \eta^{ad},$$

both of which are standard identities listed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices

Comment: Question for MathJax experts: Is there an easy way to make a Dirac slash?

Comment: `\not x` becomes $\not x$.